# Can I insert php into parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry if I worded the question wrong. In the code below, is there a way to insert php where the date is?

So this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[fergcorp_cdt_single date="08 December 2013"]') ?>`

Would become something like this:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[fergcorp_cdt_single date="<?=$date?>"]') ?>`

Is the above correct? If not, how would I write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[fergcorp_cdt_single date="' . $date . '"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will check your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use double quotes:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[fergcorp_cdt_single date=\"$date\"]") ?>
```

Comment: Yes, but why make the code wilfully less readable? You'll have to escape the double quotes in the string and are hiding `$date` from most syntax highlighters.